# Module 'appModule' is not available - jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm confused where I'm going wrong. I already added `module` in my `beforeEach`, seems it still shows the error message  `Module 'appModule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name`

Here  is my spec:

**C0001Spec.js**

```
describe("Controller : c0001Controller", function(){

    beforeEach(angular.module('appModule'));

    var $rootScope, $httpBackend, httpHandler, createController, appModuleC0001;
        beforeEach(inject(function($injector){
            $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

             appModuleC0001 = $injector.get('appModule.c0001Controller');

            httpHandler = $httpBackend.when('POST', 'C0001Login')
                        .respond({user_id : 'except'}, {password : 'except'});

            $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
            var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

            createController = function(){
                return $controller("c0001Controller", { '$scope' : $rootScope});
            };
            }));
            afterEach(function(){
                $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
               $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
           });

        it("should see the Controller", function(){
            expect(appModuleC0001).toBeDefined();
        });

        it("should use specs.js", function(){
            expect(true).toBe(true);
        });

        it("should show Incorrect Credentials in alert", function(){
            $httpBackend.expectPOS('C0001Login');
            var controller =  createController();
            $httpBackend.flush();
            expect($rootScope.success).toEqual('error');
        });

});
```

**Karma.conf.js**

```
   // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
        'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
        'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-route.js',
        'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',

        'WebContent/js/controllers/C0001Ctrl.js',
        'tests/C0001Spec.js'

],
```

Here's the **C0001Ctrl.js**

```
var appModule = angular.module('appModule', []);
appModule.controller('c0001Controller', function($http, $window) {

    var user = {};
    this.c0001Data = user;
    this.submitForm = function() {
            if(!angular.isUndefined(this.c0001Data.user_id) &&        !angular.isUndefined(this.c0001Data.password))
            {
                var promise = $http.post('C0001Login', user);

                promise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    if(data.message == 'error'){
                            alert('Invalid Username/Password');
                        } else {
                            $window.location.href =  data.url + "#/c0003";
                        }
                });
                promise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert("Invalid Username/Password");
                });
            }

            else {
                alert ("Invalid/ Username/password");
            }

    };

});
```

Comment: What is the contents of your `C0001Ctrl.js`?

Comment: I edit my Answer sir. I included the C0001Ctrl.js

Comment: check whether the path which includes your module is correct 'WebContent/js/controllers/C0001Ctrl.js'

Comment: should I use "'app/*.js'," in the karma.conf.js?
or the 'WebContent/js/controllers/C0001Ctrl.js' ?, I tried the 'WebContent/js/controllers/C0001Ctrl.js'  but the problem still persist